How to show full diff when assertEquals() fails?
I have a PHPUnit test that's failing but the test output is hiding important part of the failed data. How to make the whole data visible?
To demonstrate the issue, here's a mock test UnitTest.php:
<?php

class UnitTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
  public function testAssertingArrays()
  {
    $mock_testresult = array(
      0 => "Some short string",
      1 => "Some really long string that just keeps going and going and going but contains important clue HERE about why this whole test failed.",
    );
    $this->assertEquals($mock_testresult, array(), "Expected empty array but got non-empty array.");
  }
}

When I run it as phpunit UnitTest.php I get following output:
There was 1 failure:

1) UnitTest::testAssertingArrays
Expected empty array but got non-empty array.
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => 'Some short string'
-    1 => 'Some really long string that ...ailed.'
 )

How to make the full string visible in PHPUnit output so that I can see the word HERE in the console? I couldn't find any documentation that would have described this kind of shortening or clipping the asserted data and I don't want any shortening or clipping here.

Does this answer your question? How do I get PHPUnit to print the full input to a failed test case?

This seems to be limitation of PHPUnit right now, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5846 for details. You can workaround this by writing assertEquals(var_export($expected, true), var_export($actual, true), "Expected values converted to string to match");. It's only the array comparision which seems to be having problems.

All comments so far +1, and thinking: I can perfectly understand you're looking for that important information, but there is also a good side in not having it: A test should only have one reason to fail. Missing the information (and not having it in the $message parameter, often third) can also signal that the test is asserting too much/little. Can, not must. It's then the coders job to think twice where exactly the gap is, and often it's not in the output, but somewhere deeper down in the code. The test can be fine, but perhaps you found a sweet spot for a non-happy-path test. Dig it.
